# Remove all inline style properties which starts with 'font-'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

How can i remove all inline style properties which starts with 'font-'?

**INPUT**

```html
<div style="font-size:3px;color:red;">
  <p style="font-size:5px;"></p>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<div style="color:red;">
  <p style=""></p>
</div>
```

Comment: replace `font-[^;]+;` with `''`.

Comment: @hjpotter92: can leak into document text. `"<em>font-related</em> decisions should be left to the designers; they know best."` → `"<em> they know best."` There is no good way to do this with regular expressions only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While that HtmlAgilityPack answer looks impressive, try this much simpler code:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[style*='font-']"),
    l = elements.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    elements[i].style.cssText =
      elements[i].style.cssText.replace(/(^|;)\s*font-[^;]+/g,"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we cant parse html with regex, however I ll give it a try.

search : `style=(.*)font-[^;]+;`

replace with: `style=\1`

demo here: http://regex101.com/r/gB6nF7/3

The regex may help you in this scenario but wont go too far.

In other cases you may use what hjpotter suggested :

replace `font-[^;]+;` with `''`

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

[A no-library solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hkmnyjxs/):

```
var pattern = /^\s*font-/;
var styled = document.querySelectorAll('[style]');
[].forEach.call(styled, function(element) {
    var css = element.getAttribute('style');
    css = css.split(';').filter(function(rule) {
        return !pattern.test(rule);
    }).join(';');
    element.setAttribute('style', css);
});
```

Basically, loop through each tag with `style` attribute, split into individual rules to minimize bleed (still some possible: `background: url('boo;font-weight.png');` gets mangled; but it's really hard to implement a proper parser in a couple of lines, and the danger here is negligible), then only select the rules that do not start with `font-`, and rebuild the `style` attribute.

EDIT: Niet beat me by 1 minute, and with tighter code. +1.

Comment: +1 yourself, for providing a proper answer ;) Just edited mine to allow arbitrary whitespace, which your answer supported but mine didn't.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Haha, thanks. I am particularly jealous of that simple optimisation of filtering QSA on style having `font-` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of regex.It is just awesome!

Regex is not a good practise as html parser.